# Node.js Mongoose gets messy for complex queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have `Article`, `Comment` and `Feedback` mongoose models. It's similar to facebook scenario, where use can write `article`, write `comment` under `article`, and `feedback` (`like`, `dislike`, `share`) a `comment` or `article`.

Basic idea is, user can send an action such as `like unlike dislike undislike share unshare` with `articleId` or `commentId`. (`unlike` is to cancel `like`, `undislike` is to cancel `dislike`)

a user can `feedback` to the same `target (article/comment)` at most `twice`. one for `like/dislike`, one for `share`

Then I Do this:

1. IF `Target` (`Article` or `Comment`) exists

   a.  IF Feedback does not exist, create one. Then send back `Target` with new `feedbacks` list

   b.  ELSE (e.g. user toggle between `like` `unlike`), update the status (e.g. `deleted` -> `normal`, `like` -> `dislike`), Then send back `Target` with new `feedbacks` list
2. ELSE (Target does not exists) Report Error

Here is my implementation of the feedback.

```
exports.sendFeedback = function(req, res, next) {

    var articleId = req.body.articleId
    var commentId = req.body.commentId
    var action = req.body.action
    var meta = req.body.meta

    var Target
    var targetId
    if (articleId) {
        Target = Article
        targetId = articleId
    }
    else if (commentId) {
        Target = Comment
        targetId = commentId
    }

    //1. find the target
    //Note: will refetch when need to send json, since feedback has been changed
    Target.findById(targetId).exec(function(err, target) {
        if (err)
            return next(err)
        if (!target)
            return next(helper.getGeneralError('target does not exist'))


        //2. find the feedback
        var criteria = {}
        criteria['statusMeta.createdBy'] = req.user
        if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'unlike' || action === 'undislike')
            criteria['type'] = {$in: ['like', 'dislike']}
        else if (action === 'share' || action === 'unshare')
            criteria['type'] = 'share'
        if (articleId)
            criteria['target.article'] = articleId
        else if (commentId)
            criteria['target.comment'] = commentId

        Feedback.find(criteria).exec(function(err, feedbacks) {

            if (err)
                next(err)
            if (feedbacks.length === 0) {
                //3. Feedback does not exist, create it
                var newFeedback = new Feedback()

                if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'share') {
                    newFeedback.type = action
                    newFeedback.status = 'normal'
                    newFeedback.statusMeta.createdBy = req.user
                    if (articleId)
                        newFeedback.target.article = targetId
                    else if (commentId)
                        newFeedback.target.comment = targetId
                    if (meta)
                        newFeedback.meta= meta
                }

                newFeedback.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        return next(err)

                    //4. save to target feedbacks list
                    target.feedbacks.push(newFeedback)
                    target.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            return next(err)

                        //5. save to user feedbacks list
                        req.user.feedbacks.push(newFeedback)
                        req.user.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                return next(err)

                            //6. done
                            //Note: send the target!
                            //Note: refetch target and populate, since its feedbacks have been changed
                            var query = Target.findById(targetId)
                            populateUsersForQuery(query)
                            populateFeedbacksForQuery(query)
                            query.exec(function(err, target) {
                                if (err)
                                    return next(err)
                                return res.json(target)
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
            else {
                //3x. Found the feedback, update it
                var feedback = feedbacks[0] //must be length 1

                if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'share') {
                    feedback.type = action
                    feedback.status = 'normal'
                    feedback.statusMeta.updatedBy = req.user
                    feedback.statusMeta.updatedDate = new Date
                }
                else if (action === 'unlike' || action === 'undislike' || action === 'unshare') {
                    feedback.status = 'deleted'
                    feedback.statusMeta.deletedBy = req.user
                    feedback.statusMeta.deletedDate = new Date
                }
                if (meta)
                    feedback.meta= meta

                feedback.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        return next(err)

                    //4x. done
                    //Note: send the target!
                    //Note: refetch target and populate, since its feedbacks have been changed
                    var query = Target.findById(targetId)
                    populateUsersForQuery(query)
                    populateFeedbacksForQuery(query)
                    query.exec(function(err, target) {
                        if (err)
                            return next(err)
                        return res.json(target)
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

As you can see, the code gets very large and messy. Is there any good ways to clean it up? or is there a better coding style?

Edit: the code with promise. Can I only have 1 error handler. Also do I `return next(err)` or `throw err`?

Edit 2: the final steps of the 2 cases are the same (both fetch, populate, and send). can I combine the 2?

Edit 3: the code is not working. In the first `then`, we have a `target` as argument. In subsequent `then`s, the `target` becomes undefined

```
//1. find the target
//Note: will refetch when need to send json, since feedback has been changed
Target.findById(targetId).exec()
    .then(function(target) {
        if (!target)
            return next(helper.getGeneralError('target does not exist'))

        //2. find the feedback
        var criteria = {}
        criteria['statusMeta.createdBy'] = req.user
        if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'unlike' || action === 'undislike')
            criteria['type'] = {$in: ['like', 'dislike']}
        else if (action === 'share' || action === 'unshare')
            criteria['type'] = 'share'
        if (articleId)
            criteria['target.article'] = articleId
        else if (commentId)
            criteria['target.comment'] = commentId

        return Feedback.find(criteria).exec()

    })
    .then(function(feedbacks) {
        if (feedbacks.length === 0) {
            //3. Feedback does not exist, create it
            var newFeedback = new Feedback()

            if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'share') {
                newFeedback.type = action
                newFeedback.status = 'normal'
                newFeedback.statusMeta.createdBy = req.user
                if (articleId)
                    newFeedback.target.article = targetId
                else if (commentId)
                    newFeedback.target.comment = targetId
                if (meta)
                    newFeedback.meta= meta
            }

            newFeedback.save().exec()
                .then(function() {
                    //4. save to target feedbacks list
                    target.feedbacks.push(newFeedback)
                    return target.save().exec()
                })
                .then(function() {
                    //5. save to user feedbacks list
                    req.user.feedbacks.push(newFeedback)
                    return req.user.save().exec()
                })
                .then(function() {
                    //6 refetch target and populate, since its feedbacks have been changed
                    var query = Target.findById(targetId)
                    populateUsersForQuery(query)
                    populateFeedbacksForQuery(query)
                    return query.exec()
                })
                .then(function(target) {
                    //7. done send the target!
                    return res.json(target)
                })
                .then(null, function(err) { //ERR 1: can i propagate error out
                    return next(err)
                })
        }
        else {

            //3x. Found the feedback, update it
            var feedback = feedbacks[0] //must be length 1

            if (action === 'like' || action === 'dislike' || action === 'share') {
                feedback.type = action
                feedback.status = 'normal'
                feedback.statusMeta.updatedBy = req.user
                feedback.statusMeta.updatedDate = new Date
            }
            else if (action === 'unlike' || action === 'undislike' || action === 'unshare') {
                feedback.status = 'deleted'
                feedback.statusMeta.deletedBy = req.user
                feedback.statusMeta.deletedDate = new Date
            }
            if (meta)
                feedback.meta= meta


            feedback.save().exec()
                .then(function() {
                    //4x. refetch target and populate, since its feedbacks have been changed
                    var query = Target.findById(targetId)
                    populateUsersForQuery(query)
                    populateFeedbacksForQuery(query)
                    return query.exec()
                })
                .then(function(target) {
                    //5x. done. send the target!
                    return res.json(target)
                })
                .then(null, function(err) { //ERR 2: can i propagate error out
                    return next(err)
                })
        }
    })
    .then(null, function(err) { //ERR 3: deal all errors here
        return next(err)
    })
```

Comment: A thing to consider: you do not have to normalize Mongo docs. Ie. you can keep some of your feedback metadata on Targets. Ie. when you add a feedback, save the feedback entry, but also add a line on the target itself in "feedbacks" subcollection. You can use .select() to filter this field out otherwise, and reduce the number of mongoose hits by one like find Target where 'feedbacks.userId.like' is or isn't there or whatever works for your complex case.The downsides: a) you have to keep track of this and when removing feedback, remove at both ends and b) possibly have a multi-step transactions.

Comment: Or keep a redis handy and push the relations there.

Comment: @Zlatko I have a `feedbacks` list on user as well. since i wanna fetch all the articles liked by this user, for example.

Comment: Then maybe you can shortcut some of the checks with if (req.user.feedbacks.likes.indexOf(articleId) = 1) { earlyBailOut()}?

Comment: @Zlatko can you explain more? i dont think it's anyway a shortcut tho, but gotta see the detail

Comment: Well a good chunk of your code seems to be, for example: 1. check if there already is a like, 2. check if it's active or deleted.
If you had on the user something like:
`user.feedbacks = [{targetId: '123', type: 'Article', like: true}];`
Maybe you can use that before you even load anything.
`function (req, res) { if(req.user.feedbacks.filter(function(item) { if (item.targetId === req.query.targetId && item.type = req.query.type) {/*nowCheck if your item is a like, that is deleted and the user wants to unlike again and just next.badRequest(); */ } ...}`
Something like that, simplified for spce.

Comment: but I still need to populate feedbacks for user. it does not save any db operation

Comment: @Zlatko maybe I didnt get your point right. do you mind posting an answer? Maybe we can reduce the number of db operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose returns a promise when you use the `exec` method, so you could something like this:

```
// database
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String,
  userId: String
});

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
var Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoose-promise');

function generateData() {
  var item = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Iphone 5S',
    userId: '6500151'
  };
  var person = {
    id: '6500151',
    name: 'Wilson'
  };

  createPerson(person)
    .then(function(person) {
      return createItem(item);
    })
    .then(function(item) {
      console.log('data generated');
    })
    .then(null, function(err) {
      console.log('err: ' + err);
    });
}

function createPerson(person) {
  return Person.create(person);
}

function createItem(item) {
  return Item.create(item);
}

function getItem(itemId) {
  console.log('getting item');
  return Item.findOne({id: itemId}).exec();
}

function getPerson(personId, item) {
  var promise = new mongoose.Promise;

  Person.findOne({id: personId}, function(err, person) {
    if (err) return promise.error(err);

    promise.complete(person, item);
  });

  return promise;
}

// Generating data
generateData();

// server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/items/:itemId/person', function(req, res) {

  var itemId = req.params.itemId;

  getItem(itemId)
    .then(function(item) {
      var userId = item.userId;
      return getPerson(userId, item);
    })
    .then(function(person, item) {
      //throw new Error('something happened sorry!');
      res.send({person: person});
    })
    .then(null, function(err) {
      res.send({error: err.message});
    });
});

app.listen(4040, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at http://localhost:4040');
});
```

If you uncomment the `throw new Error('something happened sorry!');` code, you will see that your error is propagated to the error handling function.

Comment: what about the failures? like `return next(helper.getGeneralError('target does not exist'))` in my code

Comment: @OMGPOP I have updated the answer, you can see [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-then) an example handling error cases with mongoose

Comment: do i create another promise inside each case?

Comment: in the doc they use `throw new Error('Too few people!!!');`, but in my code, i call `return next(err)`. so do i throw or return

Comment: Let me create another example to clarify you in more detail, hold on.

Comment: I appended the code with promise. is it correct? also, i have some doubts on the error handling part

Comment: @OMGPOP Look at the new example that is working that I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83343/discussion-between-omgpop-and-wilson-balderrama).

Comment: What if I need to use `item` in the function(person) {} body?

Comment: in the getperson promise, why do you use `promise.error` instead of throw err? what's the diff

Comment: Because we have returned a `promise object` and to convey to the person who is invoking the function `getPerson`, we need to use the `promise object` to say him whether or not the call was successful, if you threw and error object, the error wouldn't propagate. See the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-error)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, perhaps you can simplify this and reduce number of calls to the db in general.

Right now you:

- call to check if Target exists
- call to check if Feedback by user for Target for Action exists
- if not:

  - create new feedback
  - add feedback to target
  - add feedback to user
  - reload Target with feedbacks
- if it does exist*:

  - update action on Feedback
  - reload Target

You also save the full feedback to the req.user.

Now, I'm suggesting a slight change, so that you don't do the initial two calls when you don't need to.

You can either keep your req.user.feedbacks as it is and then check there, or maybe simplify that bit, make it flag-like.

Ie (es6 syntax for computed prop name):

```
req.user.feedbacks = {
  [articleId:action]: true,
  [anotherArticle:action]: false
  // ... etc
};
```

So when you hit a request:

```
Please like article 1124:
```

You can check before you load anything:

```
exports.sendFeedback = function(req, res, next) {

  var articleId = req.body.articleId;
  var commentId = req.body.commentId;
  var action = req.body.action;
  var meta = req.body.meta;

  var targetId = articleId || commentId; // skipping error check
  if (req.user.feedbacks[targetId + ':' + action]) {
    // now you already know the user already liked/disliked stuff, and you can only flip it here
    req.user.feedbacks[targetId + ':' + action] = /like/unlike/whatever you need/
    Feedback.update({id: ...}, {$set: {action: /whatever/}});
  }
  // if it doesn't exist, create anew.
  // ... [cut] ...
```

So my point is, alter the structure of the like on the req.user.feedbacks, then you don't have to check everything everywhere.

Hope that helps.

---

[*] - Note:  you can Feedback.findOne() to avoid feedbacks.length check.

Comment: users `feedbacks` list is only an array of `ObjectId`s. I think this still requires the same number of db operation.

Comment: @OMGPOP but you have `req.user.feedbacks.push(newFeedback)` in there - unless your model `save` middleware turns this into _ids, it would save the whole thing, wouldn't it?
Anyway, even better, because it was my point exactly. Maybe you can change the user.feedbacks array to add more data then just ID, and then you do not have to make all the extra ops since you already have the user? 
Is that feasible for your use case? Would it make a difference?

Comment: ah it might be a bug. let me check. I meant to push the `_id`

Comment: Ok. Well in any case, I'd push the `[feedback._id.toString(), targetId, action].join(':')` (results in `26e51263:32174112:dislike` and then I'd do some of the prechecks before hitting the db. But of course, there are other things in play which I don't know about, so it might not work for you. Anyway, the idea is there.

Comment: since i already populated `feedbacks`, it might be better to check my feedback list first before I do any db operation. Good point

Comment: this is weird. I just removed feedbacks population for user and it still works.

Comment: I'm telling you that. The way the code is written here, it would write the whole feedback document into user's feedbacks array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) npm package. With waterfall control flow you can solve your issue.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        Target.findById(targetId).exec(function(err, target) {
        if(err)
           callback(err);
        else
           callback(null,target);
    })
    },
    function(target, callback) {
        Feedback.find(criteria).exec(function(err, feedbacks) {{
        if(err)
           callback(err);
        else
           callback(null,target);
    })
    },
    function(feedbacks, callback) {
        newFeedback.save(function(err,result) {
        if(err)
           callback(err);
        else
           callback(null,result);
    })
    }
], function (err, result) {
// result now equals 'done' 
});
```